# Python execute powershell command

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I am try to execute a PowerShell command to get the memory usage and get the result.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.call(["powershell.exe", "Get-Counter -Counter "+'"\memory\\available mbytes"'+" -MaxSamples 10 -SampleInterval 1"])
try:
    subprocess.check_output("Get-Counter -Counter "+'"\memory\\available mbytes"'+" -MaxSamples 10 -SampleInterval 1", shell=TRUE)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "subproces CalledProcessError.output = " + e.output

print output
```

It is success to execute the command, but only get the following result:

```
subproces CalledProcessError.output = 
0
```

How can I get the PowerShell result back?

Comment: Does your command (`Get-Counter -Counter "\memory\available mbytes" -MaxSamples 10 -SampleInterval 1`) work in an interactive powershell session?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
try:
   output = subprocess.check_output(
              ["powershell.exe", "Get-Counter", 
               "-Counter "+r'"\memory\available mbytes"',
               "-MaxSamples 10", "-SampleInterval 1"], 
              shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print "subproces CalledProcessError.output = " + e.output
print output
```

Notice **`True`** rather than `TRUE` supplying the `"powershell.exe"` to `check_output` and the `r` before strings with `\` in.

**But** I would strongly recommend using [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) instead of trying to get and parse PowerShell results:

```
In [4]: import psutil

In [5]: psutil.virtual_memory()
Out[5]: svmem(total=17087684608L, available=8599142400L, percent=49.7, used=8488542208L, free=8599142400L)

In [6]: psutil.swap_memory()
Out[6]: sswap(total=38059204608L, used=14400655360L, free=23658549248L, percent=37.8, sin=0, sout=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same example as above but for Python 3:

```
try:
   output = subprocess.check_output(
              ["powershell.exe", "Get-Counter", 
               "-Counter "+r'"\memory\available mbytes"',
               "-MaxSamples 10", "-SampleInterval 1"], 
              shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print ("subproces CalledProcessError.output =", e.output)
print (output.decode())
```